# A Statistics Question - Could somebody check this for me

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Below is a problem that I did. However, I am not confident that I did it right. I am hoping somebody could check it for me.

Problem:

A yarn manufacturer normally tests $36$ specimens for yarn strength. Using a
random sample of this size, he found that the mean strength is $65$lb. and
the standard deviation is $9$lb. Estimate the population yarn strength at
$90\%$ confidence level. What is the sampling error? What is the minimum
sample size required to reduce this sampling error down to half its current
value?

Answer:

To solve this problem, I use the Student T distribution.
\begin{eqnarray*}
s &=& 65 \\
s &=& 9 \\
n &=& 36 \\
df &=& n -1 = 36 - 1 = 35 \\
SE( \overline{x} ) &=& \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}
    = \frac{9}{\sqrt{36}} = 1.5 \\
CI &=& u \pm (t*)(SE( \overline{x} )) \\
t* &=& 1.30 \\
CI &=& 65 \pm 1.30(1.5) = 65 \pm 1.95 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, do I have the right answer for the first part of the question?

I am now thinking I should evaluate t* at the 99.5% level instead of the 99% level.

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong in the standard error of the t distribution, the formula is:

$$
\frac{\bar X - \mu}{s/\sqrt n}\sim T(\mathcal v)
$$

So the standard error of the mean equals:

$$
SE(\bar X)=\frac{s}{\sqrt n} = 1.5
$$

With this you build your confidence interval using the t. Note when n>30 you can use the normal approximation as well.